# Create a zip archive from multiple directories

Tags: command-line, archive, zip

My folder structure is:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
zipFolder
```

How can I create a zip archive that consists of `folder1`, 
`folder2`, `folder3` situated in `zipFolder`?

Comment: Read `man zip` or see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/zip.1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [zip](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/zip.1.html) command recursively as following.

```
zip -r /path/to/zipFolder/zip_name /path/to/folder{1..3}
```

Or using [tar](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/tar.1.html) command.

```
tar -czf zip_name.tar.gz -C /path/to/zipFolder/ /path/to/folder{1..3}
```

Note that with `-z` we are using g`z`ip to compression.